# Enum type properties in custom controls cause unrecognized tag prefix or device filter "tag"

Tags: enums, custom-controls

In the following code I created a class for which one of its properties is an enum type. For example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Bubble
{
    public enum Shape{ Circle, Square, Triangle };//enum type definition
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:BubbleFigure runat=\"server\"></{0}:BubbleFigure>")]
    public class BubbleFigure : CompositeControl
    {
       //This version
       public Shape FigureShape
       {
            get;set;
       } 
       //or this other version 
       //of course they are not both included at the same time
       public Shape FigureShape
       {
            get 
            {
                return ViewState["FigureShape"] == null ? Shape.Circle :
                        (Shape)ViewState["FigureShape"]; 
            }
            set { ViewState["FigureShape"] = value; }
       } 
    }
}
```

At the design (source)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"
 Inherits="Root.Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Bubble" Namespace="Bubble" TagPrefix="bbl" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <bbl:bubblefigure runat="server"></bbl:bubblefigure>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

At the compilation (build solution) no errors are shown, but it is successfully compiled. The control is loaded at the toolbox nicely. When the control is dropped in the source the following is shown

```
<bbl:bubblefigure runat="server"></bbl:bubblefigure>
```

rather than

```
<bbl:BubbleFigure ID="BubbleFigure1" runat="server"/>
```

The idea is to allow the selection of the shape

```
<bbl:BubbleFigure ID="BubbleFigure1" runat="server" FigureShape="Circle"/>
```

but when

```
FigureShape=""
```

is added a dropdownlist of the options should be listed as for example in the case of Boolean type the shows true or false, or the case of Color that shows all color options.

When I change the type Shape to String for example, it works great no problems on tag prefix, but input is open, when it should be restricted.

I have tried registration at the web.config, adding assembly property and so on.

This code is run with Visual Studio 2013, 2015 for Web Developer.

Please any help will be deeply appreciated.